# issue creating a double array list

Tags: java, arraylist, double

Is there any reason the fallowing code would give A compile error ?

```
Import java.util.*;

public class Storageclass
// class used to store the Student data 
{
 // creates the private array list needed. 
 private ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
 private ArrayList<double> GPAList = new ArrayList<double>();
 private ArrayList<double> passedList = new ArrayList<double>();
}
```

this is in a class access by a main file there is more in the class by it not part of this error. when I run this the two double arrayList give me this error.

```
Storageclass.java:8: error: unexpected type
 private ArrayList<double> GPAList = new ArrayList<double>(1);
                   ^
  required: reference
  found:    double
```

I am not sure why or what that error means any help would be appreciated.

~ Thanks for the help was a embarrassingly novice mistake I made, but hope full this can help some other person.

Comment: Did you at least try to search for this issue on the net before asking?

Answer (score 7):

Since all generic types `<T>` are [erased](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) at runtime to `Object` every type you put in place of `T` must also extend Object. So you can't set `T` to be primitive type like `double` but you can use its wrapper class `Double`. Try this way:

```
private List<Double> passedList = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

or since Java7 little shorter version

```
private List<Double> passedList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Also don't worry if you try to `add` variable of `double` type to such array since it will be [autoboxed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) to `Double`.

Answer (score 2):

Primitive types cannot be used as generic type arguments. Use the wrapper type `Double` (or whichever is appropriate).

Answer (score 2):

Use ArrayList<*Double*> instead of ArrayList<double>.

Comment: In fact, OP should use `List<Double>` instead of `ArrayList<Double>`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Why should a `List` be used instead of an `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 0):

cant be primitive type

```
private ArrayList<double>
```

use Double

```
private ArrayList<Double>
```